# PhantomJS PDF rendering gives different results on ec2 as compared to local

Tags: pdf, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to convert html to pdf. The html is generated by me and is hosted on s3. Here is the code snippet:

```
var markSheetinHtml = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs') ;


//check for number of supplied parameters
if (system.args.length < 5) {

  console.log('Usage: phantomjs index.js <web page URL> <ouptut path/filename> <width> <height>');
  phantom.exit();
}

markSheetinHtml.paperSize = {
  width: system.args[3],
  height: system.args[4],
  margin: {
    top: '20px',
    left: '10px'
  }
} ;

markSheetinHtml.open(system.args[1], function (status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if (status === "success") {
    //console.log(system.args[2]) ;
    markSheetinHtml.render(system.args[2]);
    console.log("Finished") ;
  }
  else {
    console.log("Failed")
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

This is the command:

```
phantomjs index.js <html-url> <local-path> <width-of-pdf> <height-of-pdf>
```

I get slight distortions on the pdf generated on ec2 versus my local machine. I initially thought it might be a versioning issue but both local and server have **2.1.1**

Not sure what is causing the distortions. Interestingly I tried a couple of popular web pages such as yelp, google and they loaded up fine. But I still shouldn't get a variation for my web page. Any ideas on how to fix or debug this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "slight distortions"? Could it be that the EC2 server is using different fonts to render the page?

Comment: Turns out that it is a font related issue which is a pain with phantomjs and has been well documented. Wondering if I should close the question or answer it myself in case somebody else finds it useful in the way I have described the issue.